# How should paragraphs be formatted in a thesis?

Tags: thesis, formatting, latex

I'm currently writing my thesis/dissertation and was wondering if there is a preferred convention for the way paragraphs are formatted and spaced in a thesis.
Would they all have indents; would they be spaced or not spaced apart from each other.
I'm doing my best to separate topics but sections / subsections but when a subsection has multiple paragraphs worth of information, I want it to look neat.

Any recommendations, advice or ideas are appreciated and welcome.
Cheers

Comment: Unless there are specific prescriptions in your place (that you should have been informed of) there are no rules. You can do whatever you think is best for the reader.

Comment: @Lewian you could turn this comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The library at your institution can probably provide you with a thesis or two from your field. You can use those as a source of guidance.

Your advisor probably also keeps copies of the theses of former students. Again, those samples can guide you and you know they were acceptable in the past.

Some universities and some departments separately have style guides that are either suggested or required.

You can also get some feedback from your advisor on early drafts and use that as a guide. You don't have to do it "blind". But a locally accepted solution is probably he best.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are specific prescriptions in your place (that you should have been informed of) there are no rules. You can do whatever you think is best for the reader.